# How can I download a word document created by a django app on the same app

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a `django` app the creates a word document from a template. After user input I make an `ajax` request to my `views.py` and create the document. After the document is created I want it to be downloaded from the server. The document is saved in the static/documents folder. In my template I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/result/',
            data : { 'values': JSON.stringify(dataJson),
                     'general': JSON.stringify(generalData)
        },
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                Download('documents/'+document.getElementById('id_file_name').value+'.docx');
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function(data) { 
                alert("something went wrong");

            }
        });

        function Download(url) {
            document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
        };
```

The `Download(url)` function is the function that downloads the document. I can get the file name of the document since it is from user input. I am currently getting a 404 error on my console.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to be declare actual file path

```
Download('http://127.0.0.1:8000/something/something/documents/'+document.getElementById('id_file_name').value+'.docx');
```

Comment: the 404 error is not there no more but I got an error in the console saying: (index):1 Refused to display '127.0.0.1:8000/documents/.docx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. –

Comment: You are saying the url is: '127.0.0.1:8000/documents/.docx, that means just .docx is a file? but filename is missing, url showing the file type only.

Comment: yes that's cause i gave it an empty file name, It gives me the same error when I specify the file name too .

Answer (score 1):

If you can use this Technic to your views:

```
    file_name = ## your file name
    file_root = ## your file root
    with open(file_root , 'rb') as f:
        wrapper = FileWrapper(f)
        mimetype = "application/force-download"
        guessed_type = guess_type(file_name)[0]
        if guessed_type:
            mimetype = guessed_type
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, mimetype)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment;filename=%s"%(download_obj.get_name)
        response['X-SendFile'] = "%s"%(download_obj.get_name)
        return response
```

Don't forget to import necessary things on the top your views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from mimetypes import guess_type
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
```

Create a new url for this views, and hit the url from ajax, you can pass dynamically file name to the view

Comment: I got an error in my terminal that says:  with open(file_root , 'rb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/documents/' and the ajax request is also responding with an error message

Comment: This means your file is missing, I am seeing any file name in your url: '127.0.0.1:8000/documents'

Comment: Your file root just from your drive root not domain, from domain it is file database url, but your file root is storage root

Comment: example of file_name:( file_name = download_obj.file.path )
example of file_root:( final_root = os.path.join(main_root, file_root) )

Comment: are you suggesting an absolute url path

Comment: Yes, see the example in 4th reply

Comment: and it also gives me a permission denied error if I use absolute path which I don't want to